# Как сохранить результат поиска регулярного выражения в php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка `"/[text12345|(.*)]/"`, которая должна искать в тексте что-то вроде `[text 171260852|test ok]` и т.п. Текст в `(.*)` всегда разный, и именно поэтому мне надо сохранять в переменную то, что нашла регулярка.

```html
<?php

$text = "abc 123 [text12345|all ok] qwerty 312"; //текст
$reg = "/[text12345|(.*)]/"; //регулярка

if(preg_match($reg, $text)) { //проверка
  //возвращать переменную = [text12345|all ok]
}

?>
```

Пример из док-и `preg_match('..', '..', $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)` не помог.

Comment: Все правильно в документации, не нужно только константу вам использовать. И внутри условия делайте `print_r($matches);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо использовать третий аргумент функции `preg_match`, однако необходимо поправить и регулярное выражение:

```
$text = "abc 123 [text12345|all ok] qwerty 312"; //текст
$reg = "/\[text12345\|([^]]*)]/"; //регулярка
$res = "";
if(preg_match($reg, $text, $m)) { //проверка
  $res=$m[0]; //возвращать переменную = [text12345|all ok]
  //$res=$m[1]; //возвращать переменную = all ok
}
echo $res;
```

[Код на PHP](https://ideone.com/EVxZFg)

[Регулярное выражение](https://regex101.com/r/YfJSZ1/1):

```
/\[text12345\|([^]]*)]/
```

**Подробности**

- `\[text12345\|` - текст `[text12345|` (скобка и `|` должны быть экранированы)
- `([^]]*)` - Захватывающая группа №1 (это значение в `$m[1]`): ноль и более символов, отличных от `]`
- `]` - символ `]`.